# What would be a fast way of detecting collision between 2 2d rotated rectangles?

Tags: 2d, collision-detection

Currently I am following this tutorial here for 2D collision detection:
http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/2d-rotated-rectangle-collision-r2604

I have found that the way of converting the projected vectors to a scalar value doesn't seem to be correct and there are false reports of collision. I tried to only take the projected x value and using that as a scalar however this runs into the rare corner case of when the axis is pointing up the x values are all 0.

If there is a way to solve this problem it would be great. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I realised I was just multiplying everything by a scalar and it would return the same result if I didn't multiply and just used the value